# How to make data available when one Controller's View calls another Controller's View?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

**Background:**
I'm trying to produce dynamically generated Factsheets, where each Factsheet has a number of ContentAreas, and each ContentArea is configured to contain a number of Panels.

I have a `FactsheetController`, a `ContentAreaController`, a `PanelController` and individual panels such as NameAndDate and AssetPanel

`FactsheetController` produces an Index View which acts as a template to load ContentAreas in to.

This is `FactsheetController`'s Index, where `Model` contains the configuration data defining which panels are associated with which `ContentArea`:

```
<div id="divTop"> 
    <% Html.RenderAction("Top", "ContentArea", Model); %>
</div>
<div id="divLeftColumn">
    <% Html.RenderAction("Left", "ContentArea", Model); %>
</div>
<div id="divRightColumn">
    <% Html.RenderAction("Right", "ContentArea", Model); %>
</div>
<div id="divBottom">
    <% Html.RenderAction("Bottom", "ContentArea", Model); %>
</div>
```

When the `Top` action method gets called on `ContentAreaController`, it passes a list of `PanelConfigurations` associated with that `ContentArea` to its `PartialView`, which is defined as:

```
<% foreach (ConfiguredFactsheetPanel panel in Model)
   { %>

    <% Html.RenderAction(panel.Name, "Panel", panel); %>

<% } %>
```

This `PartialView` renders then renders each panel that it is configured to show.

When I'm loading the `FactsheetController` I need an instance of a `Fund` object to know which `ContentAreas` are associated with that particular `Factsheet`, so I create one based on `QueryString` data. The thing is, I also need that `Fund` object in the `PanelController` because the `Fund` object contains the data I need to display. That `QueryString` data doesn't exist in the `PanelController`, because it only existed in the URL that called `FactsheetController`.

**question:**
So my question is, what's the best way for me to make the `Fund` object I create in `FactsheetController` to be available in the `PanelController`

I'd also be interested in hearing anyone's opinion on issues with this initial design.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wouldn't use query strings like that. I would extend the model object passed to FactsheetController's Index to include the data required in your other partial views and then pass that to the actions with the RenderAction method. So ConfiguredFactsheetPanel would be extended to either contain, or be replaced by a type that contained, the Fund object you require in your partial views.

I suspect that the objects that you are using in your view currently are entities driven by your persistence technology such as NHibernate or Entity Framework. If this is the case you probably won't want to change your entity definitions to satisfy your views and instead create view models.